# MySQL >, <, and missing by group

Tags: mysql, group-by, missing-data

I have two tables in MySQL that I'm comparing with the following attributes:

```
tbl_fac : facility_id, chemical_id, criteria
             10      , 25         , 50
             10      , 26         , 60
             10      , 27         , 60
             11      , 25         , 30
             11      , 27         , 31 
              etc...

tbl_samp: sample_id, chemical_id, result
            5     ,    25         , 51
            5     ,    26         , 61
            6     ,    25         , 51
            6     ,    26         , 61
            6     ,    27         , 500

              etc....
```

These tables are joined by chemical_id (many-to-many---- ugh), and there are several thousand facility_id's, and several hundred chemical_id's for each facility_id.  There are also several thousand sample_id's, each with several hundred chemical_id's for each sample_id. All-in-all, there are around 500,000 records in tbl_fac, and 1,000,000+ records in tbl_samp.

I'm trying to extract three groups of sample_id's from this dataset:

Group 1:  any sample_id where tbl_samp.result > tbl_fac.criteria  (i.e., result exceeds criteria)

Group 2: any sample_id where tbl_samp.result < tbl_fac.criteria, AND all tbl_fac.chemical_id's are present for that sample_id (i.e., result is less than criteria, and everything is there)

Group 3: any sample_id where tbl_samp.result < tbl_fac.criteria, BUT one or more tbl_fac.chemical_id's are missing in the sample_id (i.e., result is less than criteria, but something is missing)

*Here's the Question:* How do I get all three Groups efficiently in one query?

I've tried:

```
select * 
from tbl_fac 
left join tbl_samp 
    on tbl_fac.chemical_id = tbl_samp.chemical_id
```

But this only yields values that are missing for the entire dataset (not the individual samples).  I have a hackish query working that uses a third table to join tbl_fac and tbl_samp, but it is so ugly I'm actually embarrassed to post it....

As always, many thanks in advance for your thoughts on this one!

Cheers,

Josh

**EDIT:** Ideally, I would like the sample_id and Group returned -- with just one Group per sample ID (my knowledge of the data indicates that they will always fall into one of the three categories above).

Comment: What would you want returned? A table with `sample_id` and some sort of `group_it_belongs_to` column?

Comment: Yep -- exactly.  Just updated it to reflect your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer makes the assumption that there is a unique constraint on `facility_id` and `chemical_id` in `tbl_fac` and a unique constraint on `sample_id` and `chemical_id` in `tbl_samp`.  What I did was build up the query one step at a time. Whether this is efficient remains to be seen.

Group 1: any sample_id where tbl_samp.result > tbl_fac.criteria (i.e., result exceeds criteria)

```
SELECT tbl_samp.sample_id,
       'ResultsGreaterThanCriteria' AS samplegroup
FROM   tbl_fac
       INNER JOIN tbl_samp
         ON tbl_fac.chemical_id = tbl_samp.chemical_id
WHERE  tbl_samp.result > tbl_fac.criteria
GROUP  BY tbl_samp.sample_id
```

Group 2: any sample_id where tbl_samp.result < tbl_fac.criteria, AND all tbl_fac.chemical_id's are present for that sample_id (i.e., result is less than criteria, and everything is there)

```
SELECT tbl_samp.sample_id,
       'ResultLessThanCriteriaAndAllChems' AS samplegroup
FROM   tbl_fac
       INNER JOIN tbl_samp
         ON tbl_fac.chemical_id = tbl_samp.chemical_id
WHERE  tbl_samp.result < tbl_fac.criteria
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM   tbl_fac tf
                              LEFT JOIN tbl_samp ts
                                ON tf.chemical_id = ts.chemical_id
                       WHERE  ts.chemical_id IS NULL
                              AND tbl_samp.sample_id = ts.sample_id)
GROUP  BY tbl_samp.sample_id
```

Group 3: any sample_id where tbl_samp.result < tbl_fac.criteria, BUT one or more tbl_fac.chemical_id's are missing in the sample_id (i.e., result is less than criteria, but something is missing)

```
SELECT tbl_samp.sample_id,
       'ResultsLessThanCriteriaWithMissingChems' AS samplegroup
FROM   tbl_fac
       INNER JOIN tbl_samp
         ON tbl_fac.chemical_id = tbl_samp.chemical_id
WHERE  tbl_samp.result < tbl_fac.criteria
       AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   tbl_fac tf
                          LEFT JOIN tbl_samp ts
                            ON tf.chemical_id = ts.chemical_id
                   WHERE  ts.chemical_id IS NULL
                          AND tbl_samp.sample_id = ts.sample_id)
GROUP  BY tbl_samp.sample_id
```

And finally, you union all three queries together and get:

```
SELECT tbl_samp.sample_id,
       'ResultsGreaterThanCriteria' AS samplegroup
FROM   tbl_fac
       INNER JOIN tbl_samp
         ON tbl_fac.chemical_id = tbl_samp.chemical_id
WHERE  tbl_samp.result > tbl_fac.criteria
GROUP  BY tbl_samp.sample_id
UNION ALL
SELECT tbl_samp.sample_id,
       'ResultLessThanCriteriaAndAllChems' AS samplegroup
FROM   tbl_fac
       INNER JOIN tbl_samp
         ON tbl_fac.chemical_id = tbl_samp.chemical_id
WHERE  tbl_samp.result < tbl_fac.criteria
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM   tbl_fac tf
                              LEFT JOIN tbl_samp ts
                                ON tf.chemical_id = ts.chemical_id
                       WHERE  ts.chemical_id IS NULL
                              AND tbl_samp.sample_id = ts.sample_id)
GROUP  BY tbl_samp.sample_id
UNION ALL
SELECT tbl_samp.sample_id,
       'ResultsLessThanCriteriaWithMissingChems' AS samplegroup
FROM   tbl_fac
       INNER JOIN tbl_samp
         ON tbl_fac.chemical_id = tbl_samp.chemical_id
WHERE  tbl_samp.result < tbl_fac.criteria
       AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   tbl_fac tf
                          LEFT JOIN tbl_samp ts
                            ON tf.chemical_id = ts.chemical_id
                   WHERE  ts.chemical_id IS NULL
                          AND tbl_samp.sample_id = ts.sample_id)
GROUP  BY tbl_samp.sample_id
```

Comment: I **might** have a couple instances where there are duplicates of chemical_id for a give facility_id or sample_id -- but I see where you're going with this... taking a look at it now.  Thanks for the input!  Looks great!

Comment: This is very, very close.  Just so I understand, the "ResultLessThanCriteriaAndAllChems" group first links the tbl_fac and tbl_samp by the chemical_id and confirms that the result < criteria.  Then, with the "NOT EXISTS" nested query, it checks whether the chemical is missing. Correct?  One thing I'm not clear on -- why do you link "AND tbl_fac.facility_id = tf.facility_id" -- is that to make sure only the chemical_id's for the correct facility are checked in the nested query?

Comment: I don't ever seem to get any "ResultLessThanCriteriaAndAllChems" results.  Any thoughts?

Comment: To be honest, your data model confuses me a bit :-/ so I joined the subquery to the wrong field. Normally, M:M relationships have a junction table. With only 2 tables, I half expect a 1:M or 1:1  relationship somewhere. What is the primary key on these tables? And yes, the idea of the nested query is to see if a chemical is missing from the sample that (currently) has a result less than the criteria. I edited the SQL to link the subqueries back to the main query by the sample_id.

Comment: This actually works perfectly now.  There isn't a 1:1 relationship here (thought I mentioned that this was many-to-many - which is very annoying but I don't have control over it), but based on your work, I was able to take a huge leap forward and get it working.  Thanks so much!

Comment: As I was trying to solve the problem, I came up with imaginary business rules that would require your data model (to make it easier to understand for me). I wasn't saying that I thought the relationship was 1:1, just that I temporarily (and incorrectly) imagined it to be so. Anyway, glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    sample_id,
    IF(result = criteria, -1,  /* unspecified behavior */
     IF(result > criteria, 1,
      IF(nb_chemicals = total_nb_chemicals, 2, 3))) AS grp

FROM (
    SELECT s.result, s.sample_id, f.criteria, f.chemical_id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT f.chemical_id) AS nb_chemicals
    FROM tbl_fac f JOIN tbl_samp s
        ON f.chemical_id = s.chemical_id
    GROUP BY s.sample_id
) t 

CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT chemical_id) AS total_nb_chemicals
    FROM tbl_fac
) u
```

New solution:

```
SELECT
    s.sample_id,
    IF(s.result = f.criteria, -1,  /* unspecified behavior */
     IF(s.result > f.criteria, 1,
      IF(sample_nb_chemicals = total_nb_chemicals, 2, 3))) AS grp

FROM
    tbl_fac f JOIN tbl_samp s
    ON f.chemical_id = s.chemical_id

    JOIN (
        SELECT s.sample_id, 
               COUNT(DISTINCT f.chemical_id) AS sample_nb_chemicals
        FROM tbl_fac f JOIN tbl_samp s
             ON f.chemical_id = s.chemical_id
        GROUP BY s.sample_id
    ) u
       ON s.sample_id = u.sample_id

    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT chemical_id) AS total_nb_chemicals
        FROM tbl_fac
    ) v

GROUP BY sample_id, grp
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Going through it now.

Comment: I think the nested query you have in the center of this query only returns one result for each sample_id.  I actually need to compare every single result to each criteria to check whether, for a given sample_id, the sample_id has Group_1, Group_2, or Group_3 attributes. That said -- your query is very fast, but it only analyzes the first result (whatever that may be) returned from your nested query group function.  This is exactly the problem I was having when I was trying to figure this out!  Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I thought your three groups of sample_ids were known to be mutually exclusive, which would mean you only need to look at one chemical/result/criteria combo for each sample_id.  I'll think about how to make it work if that's not the case.

Comment: (by the way, I fixed it to reflect that.)

Comment: Mike - this turned out to be a great option.  Thanks!